# How to model a 1 to N relationship to satisfy single reads and writes using Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm trying to learn proper DynamoDB modeling coming from a standard RDBMS background.

The relational database I am trying to denormalise is as follows:

**TwoFactorDetail**

- Id (pk)
- Status
- PhoneNumberId (fk)

**PhoneNumber**

- Id (pk)
- PhoneNumber
- Type
- AuthAttempts

**Log**

- Id (pk)
- TwoFactorDetailId (fk)
- EventType
- CreatedAt

My single table schema is as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p3WY.png

As you can see, the same *PhoneNumber* can be used by many *TwoFactorDetail* entities.

Considering these two read / write patterns:

- Read **TwoFactorDetail** metadata including phone number, phone number type and attempts by TwoFactorDetail.Id
- Update **PhoneNumber** attempts by phone number

As you can see in the model, I am satisfying the read pattern with a known approach where the **PhoneNumber** entity linked to the **TwoFactorDetail** becomes an item within that partition. This means I can read all details for a particular **TwoFactorDetail.Id** with a single round trip to the db by using this condition: 
*PK = "DET#12345" AND (SK = "DET" OR SK Begins with "PHO")*

Now my question is how to keep **PhoneNumber** metadata consistent across partitions.

Ie. Because phone numbers can be shared across many two factor detail entities, and I would like to duplicate this data in each partition to ease reads, I am unsure how to update all items matching a phone number in a smart way so that I use the less amount of requests.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change my table model as follows:

- Move **PhoneNumber** metadata item to the **TwoFactorDetail** metadata item as additional attributes as opposed to being a sepparate item.
- Create a GSI on the **PhoneNumber** attribute making the **PhneNumber** the Partition Key so that I can get all **TwoFactorDetail** entities using it across partitions.

This picture is self explanatory: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAGc6.png

I am happy with this change because I can get all **TwoFactorDetail** metadata with just a single round trip to the DB.

On the other hand, this is what I have decided to do to keep the same **PhoneNumber** metadata consistent across **TwoFactorDetail** entities:

1. Query main table against the **PhoneNumber** GSI
2. Modify properties of **TwoFactorDetail** retrieved items as necessary
3. Send a batch write request to DynamoDb